# How can I change variable value in R apply function?

Tags: r, apply

I want to use index number to track the execution progress in `apply` function. Here is my attempt and it does not work (each time when we apply the function the index is start with 1.0). How can I fix this, i.e., change global variables in `apply` function?

```
> idx=1

> f<-function(x){
+   idx=idx+1
+   print(c("current progress", idx))
+   return(1)
+ }

> res=sapply(1:3,f)
[1] "current progress" "2"               
[1] "current progress" "2"               
[1] "current progress" "2"
```

Comment: If, as in the example, you are iterating along a numeric vector, `1:3`, why not use that directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because variable assignment within a function is lost when the function terminates. As Zheyuan Li rightly pointed out, assigning to the global environment gets around this as this way the assignment is not lost upon termination.

I prefer using the `assign()` function as you can explicitly determine where the variable is stored (not always the case with `<<-`).

```
idx=1

f <- function(x){

     assign('idx', idx+1, envir = globalenv())
     print(c("current progress", idx))
     return(1)

}

res=sapply(1:3,f)
```